# EMF Coupling from microSD writes

Tags: microcontroller, audio, adc, noise, sd

Looking for some pointers. I am having an issue with noise coupling into the onboard ADCs while writing to a microSD card. Audio from an pre-amp at 46.875 ksps

I am using a SAMD51 microcontroller (adafruit m4 express) and have tried a variety of things to lower the noise including: ferrite bead with decoupling cap (560uF  18 mOhms ESR), 10ohm resistors on spi lines, lowering the spi drive strength. The sercom used for spi is on the other side of the pcb from the analog lines.

Is it worth trying an external AREF? Decoupling analog ground?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Adding some attachments

1. Board layout
2. Schematic: this stacks on top of the feather.
3. pic of setup.
4. Example of noise from wav saved to SD card. Top is no ferrite bead or cap, middle is ferrite only, bottom is with FB + cap.

[image: Board layout]
[image: sch]
[image: setup]
[image: wav]

Comment: 560uF is not really appropriate for a decoupling cap, you should use an MLCC. Post a picture of your board layout, there may be other problems.

Comment: What's the amplitude of the noise you're showing? Microcontroller ADCs are bad, there's only so much you can do about noise like this.